# How to use pdfjs with aurelia-cli

Tags: aurelia

Has anyone got pdfjs (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) working with the Aurelia cli?

I'm getting nowhere fast with getting it up and running.

I followed the docs here (http://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/aurelia-cli#adding-client-libraries-to-your-project) and guessed that main needed to be set to webpack, but the paths in that file seem to be interpreted incorrectly.

---

------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
| Requested by: /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/src/modules/admin/admin.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package

---

------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/src/worker-loader.js
| Requested by: /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/src/modules/admin/admin.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package